# Bcrypt Longer Passwords

Tags: security, hash, passwords, bcrypt

So Bcrypt does have a limit for how long passwords can be. I have read many pages regarding this. The one thing I can't figure out is how most sites bypass this.

Most sites I have noticed don't have a max password length. Maybe I'm totally wrong about this but that is just what I have noticed. Bcrypt seems to be one of the most popular libraries for this type of thing.

So are all of these sites just not alerting users and Bcrypt is cutting the passwords to the max character limit and not alerting users? Or are they doing some special technique to allow for longer passwords?

I'm just trying to figure out how to best implement this. I would love to have no max character limit. But at the same time I want to be straight forward with users and if Bcrypt is cutting passwords users should know about that.

Any suggestions for how to handle this limitation in practice?

Comment: Where did you find that bcrypt has a max length ?

Comment: @Sylwit Well I have done tests to show it. In Node.js I register with a password with 100 characters for example and then try to login only entering the first 75 characters lets say and it comes back as a valid password. Also http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length

Comment: Didn't know. So what about sha-512 password then bcrypt ? You would be under 72 chars ?

Comment: @Sylwit So although that would work I have heard MANY people say that is a really bad idea. I asked this question here that didn't get a lot of attention http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131292/bypass-bcrypt-max-input. And the person says to hash it before isn't the brightest idea. Not sure 100% why. But I have heard that on many places. I guess because there could be more overlap or something?

Comment: @zaph Hmm. I wonder why some people would say that isn't a good idea in practice and such. Thanks for your help tho! Feel free to make an answer and I will up vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem with first running SHA-512.

According to the NIST SP 800-63-3 Draft document "Digital Authentication Guidelines" passwords SHALL accept (and use) at least 64 characters, if they accept more it must not be truncated.

In reality NIST is recommending use of PBKDF with any of SHA-1, SHA-2 family, SHA-3 family, even with SHA1 there will essentially be no collision and even if there is it is not a problem for password hashing. The key is the iteration count to slow down the attacker.

Read the answer comment by @ilkkachu in the links answer.

Comment: Cool so just running SHA-512 or something along those lines before passing it into Bcrypt then making sure the Bcrypt iteration count is high enough is basically a decent strategy for auth?

Comment: It should be a reasonably good hash, SHA-256 of SHA-512 should do.

Comment: Any other major tips I should think about when designing this? I know I'm really going off topic from my original question now but any other major tips or things I should be aware of?

Comment: You should try to use an iteration count such that Bcrypt takes about ~100ms, less if necessary due to measured performance considerations.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the question is already answered, I would like to point out two things:

1. The length of passwords *the user can enter* should not be limited, that's correct. BCrypt has no problems to work with passwords longer then 72 characters though, it will just truncate the password to this length. So accept passwords of any length, pass them directly to BCrypt or use the scheme from Zaphs answer.
2. Hashing 72 character passwords is *more than enough* to be on the very safe side. Even 20 character passwords cannot realistically be brute-forced.

   A 72 character password would allow for 1E129 combinations (without special characters). Very fast hashes can be calculated with 100Giga/second. Even in this worst case you would need about 1E110 years to expect a match, that is about 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 times the age of the universe!

**Be aware when combining different hash algorithms:**

If done correctly this can increase entropy, if the entered password is longer than 72 characters (which is rarely the case) and if the password is not random like (which is unlikely if somebody takes care to use such long passwords). A lot of ifs.

And there are pitfalls:

1. If you use the binary output of the SHA-512 then you could stumble over `\0` characters, which can lead to unsecure hashes, see this [article](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html).
2. If you use the hex/base64 representation of the SHA, you limit the possible characters for the 72 places.

Comment: Just seems like truncating a password to 72 characters isn't the best idea. Seems like passing it through SHA or some type of hash first seems like the best solution.

Comment: Ok so the best way is just to let Bcrypt cut it after 72 characters. Kinda a bummer it does that. Wish there was a better way out there.

Comment: @CharlieFish - Unless you know exactly what you are doing, I think this is the best option. And really, this is in no way a problem.

Comment: 1. Based on the current "draft specification for Special Publication 800-63-3: Digital Authentication Guidelines" passwords should never be truncated. It is acceptable to limit them to 64 characters but it is best to allow longer passwords. 2. Passwords are not brute forced, instead lists of passwords are used, 10M passwords sorted by frequency are common. 2. The uniqueness will be achieved by the initial hash.

Comment: @zaph - Dictionaries are only a problem for "short" passwords, they are out of question for 72+ passwords, but of course you know that. I took the MD5 because it belongs to the worst case, to show that even with a single iteration of the fastest hashes a 72 character limit is in no way a problem. Your comment that MD5 can be made slower with iterations (PBKDF2) only supports this statement.

Comment: Nice straw man response without actually addressing the comment issues.

Comment: @zaph - Sorry I don't get your aswer, maybe partly because of the language (english is not my native language). Do you not agree, that a warning about the pitfalls of pre hashing is necessary? I think we both strive to make code more secure, so why downvoting? I'm open for reasoning, and I removed any hint about MD5 because it has nothing to do with my answer, the statement is exactly the same still.

Comment: 1/2 Sorry about "straw man" : "a sham argument set up to be defeated", not addressing the main issues. Yes, one needs to write correct code and that includes handling the data (0x00 bytes) and encodings, this is standard programming. With MD5 out of the way the important issue is accepting a password and truncating it, this is not current best practice, rather limit the allowable length, this way the user is in charge and not potentially surprised.

Comment: 2/2 32-bytes from SHA-256 is enough entropy, one not need be concerned that not all potential 72-bits of input capability of Bcrypt (Blowfish) are not used. In any event password hash collisions are not an issue.

Comment: @zaph - Agreed that no limit would be better, but BCrypt _has_ this 72 character limit (bytes not bits). And as you said the 32 bytes of entropy is more than enough (so do the 72 bytes of BCrypt), but the pre hash will not change the entropy of the original password, it can only bring more of the original entropy into the 72 accepted characters. This will only work for very long passwords using a small base of characters. And because it is not trivial to do it correctly, i thought it a good idea to write this warning.

Comment: "it can only bring more of the original entropy into the 72" character limit of Bcrypt, that is the point. The two best practices are to (1) limit the allowable input to 72 characters (above the 64 character minimum being recommended by NIST) or (2) use the entire user input. One does not use poor security "because it is not trivial to do it correctly". Option 1 does not add complexity. Or use `PBKDF1` as being recommended by NIST. Consider that it is the users who are at risk from poor password handling, they expect and deserve good and proper security.