# Does PHP have a password_verify bug?

Tags: php, passwords, password-hash

The following code snippet should not emit 'MATCHED' because the password 'testtest' does not match 'testtesttest', but does on PHP 7.4.3 for me. Am I doing something wrong?

```php
<?php
$sPass = 'testtesttest';
$sSalt = hash('sha256','this is my salt');
$sShadow = password_hash($sSalt . $sPass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo (password_verify($sSalt . 'testtest',$sShadow) ? 'MATCHED' : 'nomatch');
```

Note, if you remove the salt references above, the code works fine. It's like the password_hash and password_verify functions of PHP have a size limitation where they no longer become accurate if the string is longer than so many characters.

So, I'm thinking this is a bug.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21479655/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/39175224/2943403

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question.  I thought you meant that `PHP 7.4.3` specifically was failing, but other versions didn't.  I expected an outlying result for that version versus other versions.  I didn't even check if it was the incorrect result for ALL versions.  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Versions 8.1.0 - 8.1.15, and 8.0.0 - 8.0.27 and 8.2.0 - 8.2.2 are affected by CVE-2023-0567 / CWE-330. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81744

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BCrypt can only handle 72 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), your salt takes up 64 characters, so only 8 characters of your password are considered.

> The input to the bcrypt function is the password string (**up to 72 bytes**), a numeric cost, and a 16-byte (128-bit) salt value.

Use the binary form of your salt to not "waste" as many characters or just don't use one at all, as `password_hash` will generate one anyway.